# Upon system upgrade error on Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, grails

I upgraded my system from Linux Mint 14 to 15 via the terminal. Before upgrading, I can successfully run grails applications. But now that I am using Mint 15, I can no longer run any of my grails app, and ended up having this error: `Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`

I have tried deleting the cache in `/.grails` and recompiled the application, but the error still exists.

Has someone encountered same error before? Please help. Thanks!

This is the full stacktrace:

```
[localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsAnnotationConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsAnnotationConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1146 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    701 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsAnnotationConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1146 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    701 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsAnnotationConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1146 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    701 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsAnnotationConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1146 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    701 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by ExceptionInInitializerError: null
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1146 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    701 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by HibernateException: IllegalAccessException trying to instantiate: org.hibernate.type.BlobType
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1146 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    701 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: post full exception log

Comment: @Jigar Joshi please refer to my edits. thanks!